# How should I move NuGet artifacts to a new TeamCity server?

Tags: teamcity, nuget

We've been using TeamCity as a NuGet server with great success. Last week I migrated TeamCity to a new server machine. The database remained where it was on an external server. I copied the artifacts folder to the new server and I can see them all listed on the project configuration page. However, the old packages are not showing up in the NuGet package feed. What else do I need to do to get the new TeamCity server to list those old packages in the feed?

Other projects that depend on older versions of these packages are currently broken because they can't be found.

New builds of those NuGet packages are showing up in the feed, but I also need all the old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks demis.  you put me on the right path to resolving this for me.

to make the answer here a little more complete and formal:

overwriting the following files:
provider-nuget.data
provider-nuget.index

in \system\caches\buildsMetadata
with the same files from the old build server worked for me (before creating new builds - not sure you'd be able to get a merge done after the fact).

Comment: I had to overwrite all of the other files in that directory. Not just those two nuget files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember now exactly what I did to fix this, but it had something to do with the files inside this folder on the server running TeamCity: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\caches\buildsMetadata

Answer (score -1):

Did you move the old artifacts from older builds as well?

Comment: Yes I did that. From my question, "I copied the artifacts folder to the new server and I can see them all listed on the project configuration page."